# How do I include the base.dtbo/pl-final.dts for a reconfigurable FPGA in my Yocto Honister image (meta-xilinx xlnx-rel-v2022.1_update2)?

Tags: yocto, fpga, xilinx, device-tree

When porting to a new Yocto Honister distro and the `meta-xilinx` metalayer `xlnx-rel-v2022.1_update2`, the `base.dtbo` device tree overlay is not generated anymore for dynamic FPGA reprogramming. How do I get the generation running again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: Add `fpga-overlay` to your `MACHINE_FEATURES`

---

The dynamic reconfigurator `fpga-manager`, recipe `fpga-manager-util.bb` creates the `base.dtbo` from the file `pl-final.dtbo`. This file has to be created from the `device-tree.bb` recipe. For the `pl-final.dtbo` to exist, a `pl-final.dts` has to be created via the call `xsct -sdx -nodisp dtgen.tcl ... -yamlconf device-tree.yaml`. The referenced YAML file contains the information, whether `pl-final.dts` has to be generated.

This YAML file is generated via `bitbake -c create_yaml device-tree`. Whether the `pl-final.dts` is created, is queried by the variable `YAML_ENABLE_DT_OVERLAY`. In the old meta-xilinx layer, this was tied to `FPGA_MNGR_RECONFIG_ENABLE`, which was active by default. In the new `xlnx-rel-v2022.1_update2` layer, this is tied to `fpga-overlay` being in your `MACHINE_FEATURES`.

So to get the `base.dtbo` again, add `fpga-overlay` to your `MACHINE_FEATURES`